# LNK2005 function pointer array "already defined" in .obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, lnk2005

Ok a little introduction into the issue: I'm working on a rendering engine(compiling in 32 bit mode) in **C++/DirectX11** in **Visual Studio 2012** running on **Windows 7** - 64 bit OS and I have a strange link error that comes up in my `Entity` class (the *Entity3D* is like the basic actor of the scene).
All of my bounding volume classes inherit from a *Shape3D* class.Each Entity has a *Shape3D** boundingVolume member in it, that is initialized to a specific shape type at initialization time.
When colliding between two *Shape3D*'s I pass them trough a function - *`bool Intersect(Shape3D* a, Shape3D* b)`* the function then checks their types(*Sphere*/*Box*/Whatever) and the type represents a number which is the index of a function in an array of function pointers:

```
bool(*IntersectArray[4][4])(Shape3D* a, Shape3D* b) = 
{
    {
        IntersectSphereSphere,
        IntersectSphereBox,
        IntersectSphereOrientedBox,
        IntersectSphereFrustum,
    },
    {
        IntersectBoxSphere,
        IntersectBoxBox,
        IntersectBoxOrientedBox,
        IntersectBoxFrustum
    },
    {
        IntersectOrientedBoxSphere,
        IntersectOrientedBoxBox,
        IntersectOrientedBoxOrientedBox,
        IntersectOrientedBoxFrustum
    },
    {
        IntersectFrustumSphere,
        IntersectFrustumBox,
        IntersectFrustumOrientedBox,
        IntersectFrustumFrustum
    }
};
```

So it's like a virtual dispatch. Ok so the `InersectArray` is the array of the functions(declared in Intersect.h) and that's what gives me the link error:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
error LNK2005: "char (__cdecl*(* Engine::Collision::IntersectArray)[4])(class Engine::Collision::Shape3D *,class Engine::Collision::Shape3D *)" (?IntersectArray@Collision@Engine@@3PAY03P6ADPAVShape3D@12@0@ZA) already defined in Entity3D.obj
File Intersect.obj
```

*Intersect.h* is **only** included in *Entity3D.cpp*, it's no included in *Entity3D.h*, nor in any of the headers that *Entity3D.h* includes.*Entity3D.cpp* only includes *Entity3D.h* and *Intersect.h*.I cleaned and rebuilt, error persists.*Intersect(Shape3D* a, Shape3D* b)* is called only in one method of *Entity3D* in the *Entity3D.cpp* file. There are no other compile errors or warnings currently in the project. What else could cause such an issue?

Comment: You have a `#pragma once` or `#ifndef` on your header? Doesn't look like it should matter, but just double checking.

Comment: yes every header file has both `#pragma once` and an `#ifndef` include guard

Comment: What is `Intersect.lib`?

Comment: oh its a type error I meant `Intersect.obj` :( sorry it's basically `Intersect.cpp`

Comment: Well, the linker is arguing with your assumptions.  It says that it is defined in Entity3D and also in Intersect.  Also something wrong with your claim that it is in Entity.  There just isn't much point in arguing with the linker, you'll lose, stop putting this definition in a .h file.  Just move it to a .cpp file and be done with it.

Comment: Your `Intersect.cpp` contains the symbol `IntersectArray`.

Comment: ok, I moved the entire definition in the Intersect.cpp file, since for now I don't need it anywhere else in the project and the built was successful.Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, I just moved the definition of *IntersectArray* in the *Intersect.cpp* file, since for now that's the only place it's needed.

Comment: This tells us your assertion that `intersect.h` was only included in one source was incorrect.